# Unperfect sorted list, but not too far

Tags: c++, sorting, std

```
int partition(std::vector<int>& tab, int size){
    int pivot = rand() % size;
    std::swap(tab[pivot], tab[0]);
    int i = 1;
    for(int j = 1; j < size; j++){
        if(tab[j] < tab[0]){
            std::swap(tab[i], tab[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    std::swap(tab[0], tab[i-1]);
    return i-1;
}
```

This code is very closed to give me a fine sorted list of integers, but still not perfect so far. I just don't understand where it is wrong.

How can I modify partition() so that the unsorted results get well sorted?

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through it in a debugger. At what point did the program do something different from what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You are always sorting the beginning of the vector. The two recursive calls need to work on distinct, non-overlapping parts of it. This can be done by adding a 3rd parameter to `quicksort`, specifying the start index in the vector to sort. This would then need to be passed to partition to only work inside that range.

The function prototypes would then look like:

```
void partition(std::vector<int>& tab, int start, int size);
void quicksort(std::vector<int>& unsorted_list, int start, int size);
```

Comment: I edit my question. I changed the code, but I just don't know where I am wrong.